# Paytm PG too many 810 status

Tags: payment, pg, paytm

I successfully docked to paytm's payment gateway. The API interfaces I called are:

1. Initiate transaction API
2. Show payment page

My test works well, but in the production environment, the payment success rate is very low and there are too many 810 statuses. I don't know why? My email: sufei5309@gmail.com

The Callback data I received:

```
'ORDERID=e7b886143afb11eca20d067239c6d80a&MID=xxxxxxx&TXNID=20211101111212800110168431460124206&TXNAMOUNT=100.00&CURRENCY=INR&TXNDATE=2021-11-01+15%3A40%3A14.0&STATUS=TXN_ FAILURE&RESPCODE=810&RESPMSG=Merchant+Transaction+Failure&BANKTXNID=&CHECKSUMHASH=XlM6ZoMTtLu60KUoddiziXRZC%2FdG%2Bf%2F%2F905c2xXXLBpJQCdZDqEoCrmQk%2BFGmQVd5eiXTLklMZ5VJ90WaOL1ruejrNhtOqGk2SAFf3S8hAo%3D'
```

Answer (score -1):

1   TXN_SUCCESS Txn Success

227 TXN_FAILURE

235 TXN_FAILURE

295 TXN_FAILURE

331 NO_RECORD_FOUND No Record Found

334 TXN_FAILURE Invalid Order ID

335 TXN_FAILURE Mid is invalid

400 PENDING Transaction status not confirmed yet.

401 TXN_FAILURE Your payment has been declined by your bank. Please contact your bank for any queries. If money has been deducted from your account, your bank will inform us within 48 hrs and we will refund the same.
402 PENDING Looks like the payment is not complete. Please wait while we confirm the status with your bank.

501 TXN_FAILURE Server Down

810 TXN_FAILURE Txn Failed.